# Standard transitions in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Back when Windows Phone 7 had it's first SDK released they had an item list template that had the transitions for the items.  Currently in the RTM tools there doesn't appear to be any support for this, can you not access the standard built-in transitions in Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone has some transitions very similar to those that exist in the phone itself.

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this yourself with Blend.

Two things you can look at.

1. Christian Schormann's blend demo in his CL02 Mix Talk.
2. Shawn Wildermuth's blog post on this topic.

[Bring Back Page Transitions to the Windows Phone List Application Template](http://wildermuth.com/2010/07/16/Bring_Back_Page_Transitions_to_the_Windows_Phone_List_Application_Template)

Comment: Sure you can, but is there no way to get access to the built-in ones?  Seems like you should be able to, to help keep things consistent.

Comment: It was removed from the project templates in the beta release. I can't say why this was done. It's probably not a bad thing if people innovate in this area to keep things interesting. It's fairly easy to do in Blend so I don't feel a lot has been lost.

Answer (score 1):

Micks' suggestion is great. To add awesomeness to your Windows Phone application, learning how to use Blend is important. Adding page transitions is quite simple to a Windows Phone app is easy and if you are looking for sample code/library, Kevin Marshall has a [good sample here](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/10/12/wp7-page-transitions-sample.aspx). I would also recommend reading [Kevin's development tips](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/kevin_marshall/archive/2010/10/26/wp7-development-tips-part-1.aspx) for Windows Phone development.